# Why is there no time in the distance equation using Hubble constant, red shift and speed of light?

Tags: redshift

So I had some problem and I think I solved it, then I began to dig out things around it and I found some equations using red shift etc. to get speed of the object in Universe relative to us and then I found this one:

distance=speed of light/Hubble constant*red shift

It took some time before I found the thing which seems to be wrong with this thing. 
How can I get the distance traveled if there is no time mentioned?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you familiar with Hubble's Law? Because this is just it, in a slightly less familiar form.

Note that the distance in this formula is the proper distance, the distance between us and some source, not the distance travelled.

Other than that, the speed of light in a sense defines our conception of time and space, so it is mentioned in the formula. ;)

Comment: Oh :D right I feel dumb now, thanks! I was thinking that this is traveled distance but of course not :D 
I will remember to think twice next time!